# I want to use JOIN for a query and I want to show only the name of the product with the image

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm practicing with queries and I have a question about JOIN.

I have these 2 tables:

```
**PRODUCTS**:

id

name

description

**PRODUCT_IMAGES**

id

product_id

image_link
```

And I want to use JOIN to combine these 2 table where I only want to see the name of the product with the specific image that is linked with the id.

I try to to that with this QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM `product_images`
LEFT JOIN `products`
ON `product_images`.`products.id` = `products`.`id`;
```

The problem now is that I get all the information, but I only want to see the name and the image.

Comment: Change `*` on `name, image`

Comment: `"SELECT p.name,i.image_link  FROM products p JOIN product_images i using(product_id)"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error with `product_images`.`id` as it should be like  "`product_images`.`product_id`" , I fixed this, kindly use this query.

```
SELECT products.name, product_images.image_link FROM `product_images`
INNER JOIN `products`
ON `product_images`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change * to name, image_link:

```
SELECT name, image_link FROM `product_images`
LEFT JOIN `products`
ON `product_images`.`products.id` = `products`.`id`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT products.id,products.name FROM `product_images`
LEFT JOIN `products`
ON `product_images`.`products.id` = `products`.`id`;
```

Instead of `*` you can give the `column names` comma separated.

You may choose `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

Select the desired columns in the select statement. It's a best practice to name the table and column together. Otherwise if a column exists with the same name in both tables it will throw an error.

```
SELECT `products`.`name`,`product_images`.`image_link` 
FROM `product_images`
LEFT JOIN `products`
ON `product_images`.`products.id` = `products`.`id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use inner join

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    i.image_link 
FROM
    products p 
    JOIN
        product_images i USING(product_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, you have data in both tables then use the below
SELECT P.name, PI.image_link FROM product_images PI
inner JOIN products P
ON P.id = PI.product_id

---

If you are sure you have data in product table but might be not in product_image then use below
SELECT P.name, PI.image_link FROM products P
left JOIN product_images PI
ON P.id = PI.product_id